# missing www folder

Tags: ios, cordova

Just installed phonegap ios-sdk now I can see PhoneGap template in XCode v4.2. But When I created a project from that template there is not www folder in the right-side panel. What I am missing?

Is there some special version I need for the latest XCode 4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow through the steps on the Getting Started with Phone Gap and iOS tutorial onthe PhoneGap website you will see a section with the word "IMPORTANT".

http://www.phonegap.com/start/

It says:

> Next step is IMPORTANT! Drag the www folder into Xcode 4. You can't
> just drag the www folder into your app's folder. It needs to be
> dragged into Xcode 4!! In my case I would drag it and drop it on
> HiWorld shown below.
>
> [image]
>
> After you drag, you should see a prompt with a few options. Make sure
> to select Create folder references for any added folders. Click Finish

I suspect that is the problem.